# Facebook FQL: Get all likes that are not in activities,books,interests,movies,music,tv

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

looks /me/likes contains a summary of the FQL ones 'activities,books,interests,movies,music,tv'.

But if you compare both outputs then /me/likes shows much more!

For example just LIKE this Tetris page:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/Tetris/107667482589691

It will appear at /me/likes but it will NOT appear in 'activities,books,interests,movies,music,tv'.

So how can i retrieve this add. data through FQL?

Comment: Any updates? I just posted a similar question except for ALL likes over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528850/get-all-of-a-users-likes-all-of-them-with-fql

Answer (score 2):

1. It DOES appear
2. These "*likes*" means that you are a "*fan*" of that (activity,movie,game)'s page!
3. Here's the FQL:

To  get the page_id only:

```
SELECT page_id
FROM page_fan
WHERE uid=me()
```

And to get the page info:

```
SELECT page_id,name
FROM page
WHERE page_id IN (
    SELECT page_id
    FROM page_fan
    WHERE uid=me()
)
```

Results:

```
[
  {
    "page_id": 107667482589691,
    "name": "Tetris"
  },
  {
    "page_id": 375266451894,
    "name": "I Play Soccer"
  },
  {
    "page_id": 17475686963,
    "name": "Hanine Y son cubano"
  },
  {
    "page_id": 91290503700,
    "name": "Inception"
  },
...etc
```